# Mintouch Wiki - Code to Save the current page

Tags: wiki, mindtouch

I have a wiki created using [Mindtouch](http://www.mindtouch.com/) software. I have created a page which has an HTML table on it. There is a button that when clicked calls a javascript function that adds a new row to the table on the page.

My question is regarding how to save the current page (now that the table has one more row than it had initially). Ideally, the user should click a save button and the current page should be saved. When you leave the page and return to it the row that has been added is no longer there.

Please note that I am not referring to saving the page when it is in 'edit mode'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to do it. Hope this link helps http://developer.mindtouch.com/DekiScript/Tutorials/Using_JEM_to_send_PUT%2f%2fPOST%2f%2fDELETE_requests_to_a_RESTful_API